Amazon SP-API Listings call does not work
I've been trying to get information about our products that we have listed on amazon seller central using the SP-API, but I keep getting error messages:
Assumed IAM role successfully.
Obtained LWA access token successfully.
403 Forbidden error. Response details:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "Unauthorized",
      "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
}
HTTP error occurred:  403 Client Error:  for url: https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/listings/2020-09-01/items?marketplaceIds=A1PA6795UKMFR9

I've set up my IAM role and can make succesful calls to this endpoint: "https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/sellers/v1/marketplaceParticipations". But for product listings it does not want to work. How do I fix this?
My code:
import boto3
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import AuthBase
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError, PartialCredentialsError

# Load credentials from JSON file
with open('amazon_creds.json', 'r') as f:
    creds = json.load(f)

# Assume IAM Role
def assume_role(role_arn, aws_access_key, aws_secret_key):
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts',
                              aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,
                              aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key)
    assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=role_arn,
        RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
    )
    return assumed_role_object['Credentials']

# Get LWA Access Token
def get_lwa_access_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):
    url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token"
    params = {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token': refresh_token,
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=params)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for bad status codes
    return response.json()['access_token']

# Custom Auth Class for AWS SigV4
class AWSV4Auth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, aws_access_key, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token, region, service):
        self.aws_access_key = aws_access_key
        self.aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key
        self.aws_session_token = aws_session_token
        self.region = region
        self.service = service

    def __call__(self, r):
        auth = AWSRequestsAuth(
            aws_access_key=self.aws_access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_secret_access_key,
            aws_token=self.aws_session_token,
            aws_host='sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com',
            aws_region=self.region,
            aws_service=self.service
        )
        return auth(r)

# Make API Request
def make_sp_api_request(credentials, access_token, region, marketplace_ids):
    endpoint = f"https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/listings/2020-09-01/items"
    headers = {
        'x-amz-access-token': access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
    params = {
        'marketplaceIds': marketplace_ids
    }
    auth = AWSV4Auth(
        aws_access_key=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
        region=region,
        service='execute-api'
    )
    response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers, params=params, auth=auth)
    if response.status_code == 403:
        print("403 Forbidden error. Response details:")
        print(response.text)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for bad status codes
    return response.json()

try:
    # Assume the IAM role
    credentials = assume_role(creds['role_arn'], creds['aws_access_key'], creds['aws_secret_key'])
    print("Assumed IAM role successfully.")

    # Get LWA access token
    access_token = get_lwa_access_token(creds['lwa_client_id'], creds['lwa_client_secret'], creds['refresh_token'])
    print("Obtained LWA access token successfully.")

    # Make the SP-API request
    region = 'eu-north-1'
    marketplace_ids = 'A1PA6795UKMFR9'
    response = make_sp_api_request(credentials, access_token, region, marketplace_ids)
    print("API response received successfully.")
    print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))

except (NoCredentialsError, PartialCredentialsError) as e:
    print("Error with AWS credentials: ", str(e))
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print("HTTP error occurred: ", str(e))
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred: ", str(e))


Since your call to getMarketplaceParticipations is working, I guess it is a different problem than an authentication / authorization one.
Per Amazon SP-API documentation, there is no /listings/2020-09-01/items endpoint (even in the new release, no /listings/2021-08-01/items). With Listing Items API you can only retrieve listing on a 1 by 1 basis, using the endpoint /listings/2021-08-01/{sellerId}/{sku} (getListingsItem).
In order to retrieve listings, the only path is to request a GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA or GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA using Reports API.
In any case, if you plan to use the Listing Items API, double check that your application is enabled for the "Product Listing Role" and, if you recenty requested it, please allow Amazon to close the case and publish the application with the latest updates.

Thank you for your response.
I am now using the python sp-api library and it works:
catalog_items.get_catalog_item(asin, marketplaceIds=['A1PA6795UKMFR9'])
This endpoint also didn't work: /listings/2021-08-01/{sellerId}/{sku}
